# How do I Test an entire Chain of Controller Calls Linked by RedirectToAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm very new to MVC (just 2 days in), but I'm wondering - is there any way to write a test for an entire chain of controller calls linked by RedirectToAction? i.e. test the whole call sequence one after another without manually coding each call.

e.g.something along the lines of:

```
MyTestMethod()
{

  var myController = new MyController(someparam1);

  ActionResult action = myController.DoSomething();

  RedirectToAction ar = action as RedirectToAction;

  // loop while the ActionResult is an RedirectToAction
  while (ar!=null)
  {
    // automatically make direct call to next redirect method in 
    // chain, is something like this possible?
    action = ar.NextMethodToCall(ar.NextMethodToCallParam1, ar.NextMethodToCallParam2);

    ar = action as RedirectToAction;
  }

}
```

So, to be clear, this is NOT a unit test, (which would only test that a single controller method returns the correct actionresult), but rather a test of the whole redirect chain.

NOTE - as this is only a test method, the MVC app will NOT be running at the time it is called. IIS will not even be installed on the test machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more reading on MVC, I've realised that what I really need is a more holistic approach to integration testing MVC apps without a browser or IIS install, e.g. something like this:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/06/11/integration-testing-your-aspnet-mvc-application/

Answer (score 1):

You could put some logging/test logic in the `NextMethodToCall()` method.

Comment: I don't understand that answer. Perhaps my question is not clear enough. NextMethodToCall() does not actually exist as a named method, but rather the code uses the RedirectToAction object to determine the "nextmethodtocall" dynamically by examining the RedirectToAction properties. The heart of the question is - how can you dynamically determine the next method to call, and fill in the parameters to that method at runtime using the ActionResult/RedirectToAction object? Any change to the actual release code should be ruled out, as we don't want to change the code just to accomodate the test.

Comment: @jimasp, You can subclass ActionResult (or RedirectToRouteResult) and add in your custom logic.

Comment: Thanks, after a little more reading, I've subsequently realised that I need a different approach (see answer).